# Is there a simple way to pivot/transpose date within a group by using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-cleaning

I have a large list of customers, each with a unique identifier. These are accounts sometimes joined to others with their own unique identifier. They are linked through a shared balance. My table shows a list of customers then in a separate column, who they are joined too, and their information. I would like one column for each joined account.Keep in mine that there are many more primary accounts

the original query and table looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust.no_                               AS'main_cust_no', 
                Datediff(year, cust.bdate, Getdate())  AS 'main_cust_Age_1', 
                dmd.balance                            AS'equity_balance', 
                cust.status                            AS 'main_cust_status', 
                cust2.no_                              AS 'jnt_cust_no', 
                cust2.status                           AS 'jnt_cust_status', 
                Datediff(year, cust2.bdate, Getdate()) AS 'jnt_cust_age' 
FROM   cust 
       INNER JOIN dmd 
               ON cust.rowno = dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dmdjnt 
                    ON dmd.rowno = dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_dmd 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cust AS cust2 
                    ON dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_cust2 = cust2.rowno 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN alta 
                    ON cust.rowno = alta.rowno_custalta_cust 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN card 
                    ON cust.rowno = card.rowno_custcard_cust 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN loan 
                    ON cust.rowno = loan.rowno_custloan_cust 
WHERE  dmd.type = 'equity' 
       AND dmd.balance > '0.00' 
       AND cust.status <> 'closed' 
       AND cust.no_ = '424242'
```

.

```
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
| main_cust_no | main_cust_Age_1 | equity_balance | main_cust_status | jnt_cust_no | jnt_cust_status | jnt_cust_age |
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       424242 |              45 |            100 | active           |       18111 | closed          |           81 |
|       424242 |              45 |            100 | active           |       24222 | active          |           60 |
|       424242 |              45 |            100 | active           |       36333 | active          |           66 |
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I have tried This:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT cust.no_                               AS'main_cust_no', 
                        Datediff(year, cust.bdate, Getdate())  AS 
                        'main_cust_Age_1', 
                        dmd.balance                            AS 
                        'equity_balance', 
                        cust.status                            AS 
                        'main_cust_status', 
                        cust2.no_                              AS 'jnt_cust_no', 
                        cust2.status                           AS 
                        'jnt_cust_status', 
                        Datediff(year, cust2.bdate, Getdate()) AS 'jnt_cust_age' 
        FROM   cust 
               INNER JOIN dmd 
                       ON cust.rowno = dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dmdjnt 
                            ON dmd.rowno = dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_dmd 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN cust AS cust2 
                            ON dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_cust2 = cust2.rowno 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN alta 
                            ON cust.rowno = alta.rowno_custalta_cust 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN card 
                            ON cust.rowno = card.rowno_custcard_cust 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN loan 
                            ON cust.rowno = loan.rowno_custloan_cust 
        WHERE  dmd.type = 'equity' 
               AND dmd.balance > '0.00' 
               AND cust.status <> 'closed' 
               AND cust.no_ = '455') AS t 
       PIVOT( Max(main_cust_no, equity_balance) 
            FOR jnt_cust_no IN ( ?, 
                                 ?, 
                                 ?, 
                                 ?, 
                                 ? ) ) AS pivot_table;
```

I would like it to look like this

```
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
| main_cust_no | main_cust_Age_1 | equity_balance | main_cust_status | jnt_cust1_no | jnt_cust1_status | jnt_cust1_age | jnt_cust2_no | jnt_cust2_status | jnt_cust2_age | jnt_cust3_no | jnt_cust3_status | jnt_cust3_age |
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
|       424242 |              45 |            100 | active           |        18111 | closed           |            81 |        24222 | active           |            60 |        36333 | active           |            66 |
+--------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: While probably doable, this is going to be awkward in SQL because the output you want doesn't fit the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) well. It would probably be far easier and tidier to run the SQL output through a script (written in any typical imperative programming language you like) that rearranges it to fit the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bc469cbd63da864ce1642efa56e357e)**

First you need to unpivot your table and create the labels for each data element:

```
SELECT * into tmpResult 
FROM 
(
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'main_cust_Age' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field,  
       CAST(main_cust_Age_1 as nvarchar) as value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'equity_balance' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field, 
       CAST(equity_balance as nvarchar) as value           
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'main_cust_status' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field, 
       main_cust_status as value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'jnt_cust_no' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field,    
       CAST(jnt_cust_no as nvarchar) as value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'jnt_cust_status' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field,    
       jnt_cust_status as value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT main_cust_no, 
       'jnt_cust_age' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_cust_no) as nvarchar) as field, 
       CAST(jnt_cust_age as nvarchar) as value         
FROM Table1
) as t
;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Then you use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.field) 
            FROM tmpResult c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT main_cust_no, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select main_cust_no
                    , field
                    , value
                from tmpResult
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(value)
                for field in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]